# Select on multiple tables which are a result of an other select

Tags: sql, linux, function

I need to create a function which searches all the tables that contain a certain field

```
select distinct(table_name) from information_schema.columns where column_name='fieldNeeded';
```

and then, to do a query on each table that is found:

```
select * from table_name where ... <parameters> ;
```

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function on a column, it's a part of select distinct and it works on the whole selected rows!!! I.e. simply do `select distinct table_name from...` to make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL-server...

You can use the result of the first query is input for your cursor (a for-loop in T-SQL) in where you dynamically create and execute the query. Note 'dynamic sql' is creating an sql-command in string (varchar) format and then run that string as sql-commant (something like: EXEC @SqlCommand), although there are other (better) ways to execute dynamic sql.

To finish things up nicely, you can start with creating a temp-table and insert the result in the temp-table. And in each iteration of the cursor you can store the result in the temp-table

In pseudo-code it would look something like:

```
Create #TempTable with some columns

Create Cursor for:
    select distinct(table_name) 
    from information_schema.columns 
    where column_name='fieldNeeded'

For each element in the cursor (fetch next @table_name from the cursor)

    DECLARE @SqlCommand VARCHAR(250) = 
    'Insert Into #TempTable select * from ' + @table_name + 'where ... <parameters>'

    PRINT @SqlCommand -- can be useful to check the code you created
    EXEC @SqlCommand

End of cursor

SELECT * FROM #TempTable
```